# Python Flask - Can't return boolean true

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple `JSON` array in `Python` `Flask` like this..

```
response = [{
    "success" : true,
    "sessionid" : "sdf3452",
    "border" : {
        "top"    : "452",
        "left"   : "454",
    }
}]

js = json.dumps(response)
resp = Response(js, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
return resp
```

When I try this I get an error complaining that the true value does not exist...

```
NameError: name 'true' is not defined
```

Any ideas why I can't return a boolean true?

Comment: What you have is not a JSON array. It is Python source code. There is no `true` in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question, `python` boolean values `true` and `false` are capitalized.

```
response = [{
    "success" : True,
    "sessionid" : "sdf3452",
    "border" : {
        "top"    : "452",
        "left"   : "454",
    }
}]

js = json.dumps(response)
resp = Response(js, status=200, mimetype='application/json')
return resp
```

This works fine now